# Node.js Return value from a function that makes an Http Call

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a requirement to build a function in Node.js that invokes a synchronous REST API, manipulates the result a little bit and then returns a value.
Here is how the function looks like:

```
function getGerritChangeId(changeNumber){
    const endpointUrl = "https://git.xxxx/a/changes/contentpipeline~"+changeNumber;
    var changeId;
  
     const req = https.request(endpointUrl, options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        changeId = JSON.parse(chunk.replaceAll(")]}'", "")).change_id;
        console.log("Change Id (Inside Http Res): "+changeId);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
        console.log("Change Id (Inside end): "+changeId);
      });
    });
    
    req.end();  
    console.log("Change Id (Before Return): "+changeId);
    return changeId; 
  }
```

My requirement is to return the changeId (found after parsing the response JSON) from the function getGerritChangeId.
As expected, because of asynchronicity, the HTTP response is handled in parallel with the overall function body. So what I see is:

```
console.log("Change Id (Inside Http Res): "+changeId);  -> Returns right value
console.log("Change Id (Inside end): "+changeId); -> Returns right value
console.log("Change Id (Before Return): "+changeId); -> Returns undefined, as this is executed before the value is set.
```

What would be the best way to handle this? I realize my function getGerritChangeId is a synchronous wrapper on top of an asynchronous HTTP call. So do I need to use a Promise? If yes, any references on how to go about it?

Comment: I highly recommend you use `fetch()` instead which is promise-based

Comment: Your requirement is invalid. It is impossible to write a synchronous wrapper around an asynchronous API.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. It helps to validate that the approach is not feasible. It is essentially trying to beat a key Node Js feature

Comment: *"trying to beat a key Node Js feature"*: no, not really, you can surely get the sequence to execute in the order that you want. Just don't call that *synchronous*, and instead embrace asynchronous behaviour.